# How to get only the first error with psql --single-transaction

Tags: postgresql, errors, psql

I'm typing something like:

```
psql --single-transaction --quiet my_db < my_file.sql
```

When the script fails I get many lines saying: `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`.

In linux I can use `| more` to pipe the result, but in Windows thats may take a lot of time (to show the first error, because the pipe is not a pipe).

My question:

**Is there a way to get only the first error?**

- The .sql file is generated by me, I can add some sets or commands if necesary
- Y try --file (I obtain the same behavior)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may just ask it to stop on the first error:

```
$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on --single-transaction ...
```

Comment: Spot on. Was about to suggest the same: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES